# Is this an optimization done by C# compiler?

Tags: c#, optimization, lambda

I create a batch of anonymous functions by lambda expression. And I want to use TaskId to differ the anonymous functions from each other.
Here is the code:

```
int count = 3;
int i;
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    i = 0;
    Func<bool, Task<int>> func = async (b) =>
    {
        return j;
    };
    while (i++ < count)
    {
        var task = func(true);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Task Result:{0} TaskId:{1}",
            task.Result, task.Id));
    }
}
```

Here is the output

```
Task Result:0 TaskId:1
Task Result:0 TaskId:1
Task Result:0 TaskId:1
Task Result:1 TaskId:2
Task Result:1 TaskId:2
Task Result:1 TaskId:2
Task Result:2 TaskId:3
Task Result:2 TaskId:3
Task Result:2 TaskId:3
Task Result:3 TaskId:4
Task Result:3 TaskId:4
Task Result:3 TaskId:4
Task Result:4 TaskId:5
Task Result:4 TaskId:5
Task Result:4 TaskId:5
Task Result:5 TaskId:6
Task Result:5 TaskId:6
Task Result:5 TaskId:6
Task Result:6 TaskId:7
Task Result:6 TaskId:7
Task Result:6 TaskId:7
Task Result:7 TaskId:8
Task Result:7 TaskId:8
Task Result:7 TaskId:8
Task Result:8 TaskId:9
Task Result:8 TaskId:9
Task Result:8 TaskId:9
Task Result:9 TaskId:10
Task Result:9 TaskId:11
Task Result:9 TaskId:12
```

As you can see, the TaskId changed since the result is greater than 8. I'm wondering to know the reason of this phenomenon. Thanks for your help:)

Comment: It is interesting, from what I can tell it is reusing the task instance (object.ReferenceEquals is true when comparing `task` to the previous value) for a while but it is not clear why.

Comment: @mikez Yeah. But I don't know why the return value will impact the reusing.

Comment: The tasks are getting cached somewhere. Run that code in a method twice in a row. For <= 8, the same task ids will repeat but above that they are new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the compiler, per se, but the .NET framework that is doing the caching. Look at the code for [`AsyncMethodBuilder`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs) which the compiler uses to manage the generated state machines for async methods. It looks like `SetResult` does some caching in `GetTaskForResult`. There is some very specific code for caching basic value types including this:

```
// For Int32, we cache a range of common values, e.g. [-1,4).
else if (typeof(TResult) == typeof(Int32))
{
    // Compare to constants to avoid static field access if outside of cached range.
    // We compare to the upper bound first, as we're more likely to cache miss on the upper side than on the 
    // lower side, due to positive values being more common than negative as return values.
    Int32 value = (Int32)(object)result;
    if (value < AsyncTaskCache.EXCLUSIVE_INT32_MAX &&
        value >= AsyncTaskCache.INCLUSIVE_INT32_MIN)
    {
        Task<Int32> task = AsyncTaskCache.Int32Tasks[value - AsyncTaskCache.INCLUSIVE_INT32_MIN];
        return JitHelpers.UnsafeCast<Task<TResult>>(task); // UnsafeCast avoids a type check we know will succeed
    }
}
```

And we see that:

```
/// <summary>The minimum value, inclusive, for which we want a cached task.</summary>
internal const Int32 INCLUSIVE_INT32_MIN = -1;
/// <summary>The maximum value, exclusive, for which we want a cached task.</summary>
internal const Int32 EXCLUSIVE_INT32_MAX = 9;
```

Which is why 8 is the magic cutoff. Notably -1 should get cached too and from my tests it is.

Answer (score 0):

The ambda expressions are storing variables and not values. Your expression is async so i think the threads are messing up the results. Try without the async magic, it will show the correct results.

Comment: The code is a sample. I really want to know why the messing up happens.